# no kbmMW forms component in the Delphi IDE Tool Palette

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I have Delphi XE7.1 Ent, kbmMemtable Pro, kbmMW Ent installed.
Thanks to Kim Madsen, it was successfully installed.
However no one kbm objects/forms component appears in Delphi IDE Tool Palette.
How to fix it?

Comment: did you click on *install* for the visual component after compiling it?

Comment: yes, i did.I see 2 design packages and 15 tabs in tool palette full of components. However in File/New there are no one kbmMW wizards

Comment: so **my edit to your question is wrong**: I couldn't get what you meant with the *IDE repository* and I assumed you couldn't see the component in the tool palette. Please consider to edit the question again, sorry

Comment: sorry. in other words, I compiled runtime package and compiled & installed design time package of kbmMW successfully. Now in the tool palette there is a lot of kbmMW and kbmMemtable components. However when I\d like to create customized service, there is no tab in File/New/. I canot even create a new service from TkbmMWCustomService manually.

Comment: Don't you just add them on a Datamodule?

Comment: Hmm, how it can help me in the inheritance from TkbmMWCustomService ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project. For example a VCL forms project.
Now you will see the wizards in File/New/Other/Components4Developers.

Or take advantage of one of the many sample projects and adapt/alter it to your needs.

best regards
Kim/C4D